# Taking a list of functions(with parameters) as input in python

Tags: python, function

My intention is to do this:

```
config = {"methods": ["function1(params1)", "function2(params2)"] }
```

This I read from a json file. So to use it, I need to pass it to another function as follows:

```
for method in config[methods]:
    foo(global()[method])
```

I know this wont work as the globals only converts the function name from a string to function but i need this to work for functions with parameters as well.

Also I have thought of this:

```
config = {"methods": [("function1", params1) , ("function2", params2)] }
for method in config[methods]:
    foo(global()[method[0]](method[1]))
```

This will work but I might have some functions for which I wouldn't require parameters. I don't want to have a condition check for whether the second entry in the tuple exists.

Is there any other way around this? I am open to change in the entire approach including the input format. Please do suggest.

Comment: Where is the JSON data coming from? Can you change how it is formatted? Can users *change* the JSON data at all? Because if they can you have a security problem, a huge one.

Comment: If you really want to read a list of Python function signatures, and then use them as functions... why not just import a Python module?

Comment: @ire_and_curses : It is a part of a config file and I have other parameters in the dictionary. I have only mentioned this part in the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It is a test suite. It is intended for user input. Security is not an issue

Comment: @Kevin: Then separate function name and arguments. Use a mapping of known functions to look the functions up, not `globals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified example that works with any number of parameters:

```
from re import findall

def a(*args):
    for i in args:
        print i

config = {"methods": ["a('hello')", "a('hello','bye')", "a()"]}

for i in config['methods']:
    x,y = findall(r'(.*?)\((.*?)\)', i)[0]
    y = [i.strip() for i in y.split(',')]
    globals()[x](*y)


[OUTPUT]
'hello'
'hello'
'bye'
```

[**DEMO**](http://repl.it/TEV/1)

Comment: @Kevin, Glad you like it. Racked my brains over this one for a good half-hour

Comment: You understood my question perfectly. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight modification of @sshashank124 answer, which is simpler because it accepts the data differently. I think using `'f(arg1, arg2)'` is not so intuitive, and gets very repetitive. Instead, I make it to dictionary pointing to a list of lists, each one represents an execution and only contains the arguments, thusly:

```
config = { "methods": {"a": [ ["hello"], ["hello","bye"], [] ]} }
```

means:

```
a("hello")
a("hello", "bye")
a()
```

I'm not sure it's any better than Shank's version, but I think it's easier to understand:

```
def a(*args):
    for i in args:
        print i

config = { "methods": {"a": [ ["hello"], ['hello','bye'], [] ]} }

for f,args in config['methods'].items():
    for arg in args:
        globals()[f](*arg)
```

**[DEMO](http://repl.it/TEV/4)**